# Android Cursor Loaders getting wrong data

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have been playing with my app on tablet mode - master detail view with fragments  trying to see how it goes and it seems rather randomly it will call one loaders with another loader's data, causing crashes and weird data return.

I have 4 loaders currently

- DetailLoader - loads main movie details from movie table
- ReviewLoader - loads reviews from reviews table
- YoutubeLoader - Loads youtube videos from table
- Favorite Loader - Loads favorite entry, used to see if in favorites already

the trouble is randomly, the favorites will get the data from the movie request, or visa versa, or some other weird combination.
This can happen more often if I am changing between the movies fast

```
static final int DETAIL_LOADER=0;
static final int YOUTUBE_LOADER=1;
static final int REVIEW_LOADER=2;
static final int FAVORITE_LOADER=3;
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAIL_LOADER,null,new DetailLoader());
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

then inside `DetailLoader` 's `OnLoadFinished`

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(YOUTUBE_LOADER, null, new YoutubeLoader());
getLoaderManager().initLoader(REVIEW_LOADER, null, new ReviewLoader());
getLoaderManager().initLoader(FAVORITE_LOADER,null,new FavoriteLoader());
```

each XLoader object is a different object that implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`

Comment: you have a bug then, definitely

Comment: @pskink there *is* a reason I am asking on here , there is either a bug or some random android behaviour I don't know about

Comment: hmm code looks ok, you even have different `LoaderCallback`s for each `Loader`...

Comment: That's what confused me, i have in the end rather then trying to run together, assuming android will keep them seperate, now chained them so one finishing loading it's data starts the other, and that seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. Solved it by adding "break;" at the end of my onLoadFinished switch case statements.

```
 public void onLoadFinished (Loader < Cursor > loader, Cursor data){

        switch (loader.getId()){
            case LOADER_1:
                mBinCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
                break;
            case LOADER_2:
                ((RoomCursorRecyclerAdapter) mRoomRecyclerView.getAdapter()).swapCursor(data);
                break;
```